# Splitting string by multiple delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string of names. I am looking to split it based on names between double quotes. I used the following code to split the names.

```
String []splitterString=str.split("\"");

for (String s : splitterString) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I get the output as:

```
[
Hossain, Ziaul
,
Sathiaseelan, Arjuna
,
Secchi, Raffaello
,
Fairhurst, Gorry
]
```

I need to store just the names from these. I am not sure how to do that.

This is the string:
["Hossain, Ziaul","Sathiaseelan, Arjuna","Secchi, Raffaello","Fairhurst, Gorry"]

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: they are stored in `splitterString` - what is your question?

Comment: Is your input string ["Hossain, Ziaul","Sathiaseelan, Arjuna","Secchi, Raffaello","Fairhurst, Gorry"] or it doesn't include square brackets ?

Comment: what is the desired output? "looking to split it based on names" is a bit confusing

Comment: @ManguSinghRajpurohit yes the input includes the brackets

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes they are stored in splitterString. But I need to extract just the names 1. Hossain, Ziaul 2. Sathiaseelan, Arjuna 3.   and so on and not the '[' and ','

Comment: This `str` seems to have come from an ArrayList already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following solution may help you out :-

```
String str = "[\"Hossain, Ziaul\",\"Sathiaseelan, Arjuna\",\"Secchi, Raffaello\",\"Fairhurst, Gorry\"]";


String [] str1 = str.split("\\[\"|\",\"|\"\\]");
for (int iCount = 0; iCount < str1.length; iCount++)
{
   System.out.println(str1[iCount]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works!